# How to extract attribute value from NodeList object while parsing SOAP body

Tags: java, xml, soap, xml-parsing

So i have an xml soap message that is look like that:

```
...
<FinalValueFee1 currencyID="USD">8.0</FinalValueFee>
<FinalValueFee2 currencyID="ILS">6.0</FinalValueFee>
<FinalValueFee3 currencyID="EUR">1.0</FinalValueFee>
<FinalValueFee4 currencyID="USD">4.0</FinalValueFee>
...
```

After setting an object of `SOAPMessage` and `SOAPBody` i have the ability to pick up the values of each element by:

```
SOAPBody m_soapBody.getElementsByTagName("FinalValueFee1").item(0).getTextContent();
```

How should i pick the `currencyID` for each one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m_soapBody.getElementsByTagName("FinalValueFee1").item(0)` returns a `Node` object. The various methods available under such an object can be viewed here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html

By looking into the docs, either of the following should get the value you seek:

```
    node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("currencyID").getNodeValue();
    node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("currencyID").getTextContent();
```